# Save An Email As PDF Without Displaying SaveAs Dialog Box

Tags: vba, pdf, outlook

I have an Outlook macro that saves an email as a PDF. It is passed the name of the file (EmailName) from the subject\input box and the folder (strFolder) to save to.

I am using PDFTK to create the PDF.

I show the SaveAs dialog box to save.

```
If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
    strCurrentFile = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
```

Is there a way of saving the email as PDF without showing the SaveAs dialog box to confirm the file name\folder?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Public Function EVAL_SaveAsPDFfile(EmailName As String, strFolder As String) As String
'====================================================
' Description: Outlook macro to save a selected item in the pdf-format
' Requires Word 2007 SP2 or Word 2010
' Requires a reference to "Microsoft Word Object Library"
' (version is 12.0 or 14.0)
' In VBA Editor; Tools-> References...
'====================================================
' also microsoft shell controls and automation
'=============================================
' set share location
'=============================================
'    On Error GoTo ErrorHandling
'Root folder
  Dim strTempFileName As String
  strTempFileName = "\\asfs1\cons\clients"
  If (Right(strFolder, 1) = "\") Then
  Else
    strFolder = strFolder + "\"
  End If

'PDFTK
  Dim program As String
  program = strTempFileName & "\crm\pdftk.exe"

  Dim directoremail As String
  directoremail = "email@address.co.uk"

  FUNC_SYSTEM_FolderExistsCreate (strFolder)
  FUNC_SYSTEM_FolderExistsCreate (strTempFileName)

  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  If FSO.FolderExists(strTempFileName) Then
    'Get all selected items
    Dim MyOlNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Set MyOlNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set MyOlSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

    'Make sure at least one item is selected
    If MyOlSelection.Count <> 1 Then
      Response = MsgBox("Please select a single item", vbExclamation, "Save as PDF")
      Exit Function
    End If

    'Retrieve the selected item
    Set MySelectedItem = MyOlSelection.Item(1)

    'Get the user's TempFolder to store the item in
    Dim tmpString As String
    Dim tmpFileName As String, newFileName As String

    tmpString = strTempFileName & "\crm\temp\" & Format(Now, "yyyyMMddHHmmss")

    'construct the filename for the temp mht-file
    tmpFileName = tmpString & ".mht"
    'newFileName = tmpString & ".pdf"
    newFileName = EmailName & ".pdf"

    'Save the mht-file
    MySelectedItem.SaveAs tmpFileName, olMHTML

    'Create a Word object
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.document
    Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    'Open the mht-file in Word without Word visible
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=tmpFileName, Visible:=False)

    'Define the SafeAs dialog
    Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
    Set dlgSaveAs = wrdApp.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)

    'Determine the FilterIndex for saving as a pdf-file
    'Get all the filters
    Dim fdfs As FileDialogFilters
    Dim fdf As FileDialogFilter
    Set fdfs = dlgSaveAs.Filters

    'Loop through the Filters and exit when "pdf" is found
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    For Each fdf In fdfs
      i = i + 1
      If InStr(1, fdf.Extensions, "pdf", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Exit For
      End If
    Next fdf

    'Set the FilterIndex to pdf-files
    dlgSaveAs.FilterIndex = i

    'Get location of My Documents folder
    Dim WshShell As Object
    Dim SpecialPath As String
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    SpecialPath = WshShell.SpecialFolders(16)

    'Construct a safe file name from the message subject
    Dim msgFileName As String
    msgFileName = MySelectedItem.subject

    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    oRegEx.Global = True
    oRegEx.Pattern = "[\\/:*?""<>|]"
    msgFileName = Trim(oRegEx.Replace(msgFileName, ""))

    'Set the initial location and file name for SaveAs dialog
    '=============================================
    ' set default location
    '=============================================
    Dim strCurrentFile As String

    If (TypeOf MyOlSelection.Item(1) Is Outlook.mailitem) Then
      strCurrentFile = GetClientFolder(MyOlSelection.Item(1))
    End If
    If strCurrentFile = vbNullString Then
      dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = strFolder
    Else
      If FileFolderExists(strCurrentFile & "\") Then
        dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = strCurrentFile & "\"
      Else
        dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = strFolder
      End If
    End If

    dlgSaveAs.Execute
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' minimize outlook to show save as dialog
    Set OutlookObj = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    OutlookObj.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = olMinimized

    Dim objShell As Shell
    Set objShell = New Shell
''    objShell.MinimizeAll

    'Show the SaveAs dialog and save the message as pdf
    newFileName = Replace(newFileName, ":", " -", Start:=1)
    dlgSaveAs.InitialFileName = strFolder + newFileName
    dlgSaveAs.Execute

    If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
      strCurrentFile = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
      'Verify if pdf is selected
      If Right(strCurrentFile, 4) <> ".pdf" Then
        Response = MsgBox("Sorry, only saving in the pdf-format is supported." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Save as PDF instead?", vbInformation + vbOKCancel)
        If Response = vbCancel Then
'            wrdDoc.Close
'            wrdApp.Quit
          Exit Function
        ElseIf Response = vbOK Then
          intPos = InStrRev(strCurrentFile, ".")
          If intPos > 0 Then
            strCurrentFile = Left(strCurrentFile, intPos - 1)
          End If
          strCurrentFile = strCurrentFile & ".pdf"
        End If
      End If

    'Save as pdf
      wrdApp.ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=newFileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=0, To:=0, Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False

      EVAL_SaveAsPDFfile = strCurrentFile

    ' now append the temp file with the chosen one
    '=============================================
    ' set pdftk location
    '=============================================

      Dim tempPDF
      tempPDF = tmpString & " temp.pdf"

    ' if existing file, append to old
      If objFSO.FileExists(strCurrentFile) Then
        Dim command As String
        command = Chr(34) & program & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & newFileName & Chr(34) & " " & Chr(34) & strCurrentFile & Chr(34) & " cat output " & Chr(34) & tempPDF & Chr(34)

        Dim oShell
        Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        fdsk = oShell.Run(command, 1, True)
        Set oShell = Nothing

'        MsgBox ("Temp: " & tempPDF + ", Current: " & strCurrentFile)
        objFSO.CopyFile tempPDF, strCurrentFile, True
      Else
        ' create file to be overwriten
        Dim fsonewpdf As Object
        Set fsonewpdf = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim oFile As Object
        Set oFile = fsonewpdf.CreateTextFile(strCurrentFile)
        oFile.WriteLine "test"
        oFile.Close
        Set fsonewpdf = Nothing
        Set oFile = Nothing

        objFSO.CopyFile newFileName, strCurrentFile, True
      End If

'copy new file to saveas file
    'delete temp files
      If objFSO.FileExists(tempPDF) Then
        objFSO.DeleteFile tempPDF
      End If
      If objFSO.FileExists(newFileName) Then
        objFSO.DeleteFile newFileName
      End If

    'close the document and Word
      wrdDoc.Close
      'wrdApp.Quit

      If objFSO.FileExists(tmpFileName) Then
        objFSO.DeleteFile tmpFileName
      End If
    Else
    ' close the document and Word
      wrdDoc.Close
      'wrdApp.Quit
    End If

    If objFSO.FileExists(tmpFileName) Then
      objFSO.DeleteFile tmpFileName
    End If

' maximize outlook now that we have finished
''OutlookObj.ActiveExplorer.WindowState = olMaximized

'objShell.UndoMinimizeALL
    Set objShell = Nothing
    Set dlgSaveAs = Nothing

'Cleanup
    Set MyOlNamespace = Nothing
    Set MyOlSelection = Nothing
    Set MySelectedItem = Nothing
    Set wrdDoc = Nothing
    Set wrdApp = Nothing
    Set oRegEx = Nothing
  End If

'ErrorHandling:
'    MsgBox "The Email failed to save, please delete the Evaluation record and try again or manually save the email as a PDF and add it.", vbOKOnly, "Error Saving Email"
'    EVAL_SaveAsPDFfile = ""
End Function
```

Comment: So where would you save it? If saving it directly

Comment: I would be saving it to a network drive. The folder varies depending on email address but structure is fixed. So I just want to be able to save the email as a PDF using PDFTK or another method to a fixed location without any dialog displaying.